# can I delete an attribute which configurable is false?

Tags: javascript

if I set an attribute with configurable: false, can I change or delete it any more? Just like below:

```
var a = {
test: {
// there are some function
}
}
Object.defineProperty(a, 'test', {configurable: false, value: null})
```

I want to do something like this `a.test.b = '1'`again, but now test is null and no-configurable.
Maybe this question is boring, but I just don't want to get something cannot be changed or used with js code.

I have try to redefined: `Object.defineProperty(a, 'test', {configurable: true, value: {}})`
or want to make a new 'test' with `delete a.test`
nothing worked.

```
Object.defineProperty(a, 'test', {configurable: false, value: null});
delete a.test; // error
a.test; // null, and I want it be {} with some code.
```

```
Object.defineProperty(a, 'test', {configurable: false, value: null});
// there is some code to make sure below code right.
a.test.b = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't *delete* the property, but if you use `writable: true`, you *will* be able to reassign it:

```js
'use strict';
var a = {
  test: {
    b: 'x'
  }
}
Object.defineProperty(a, 'test', {
  configurable: false,
  writable: true,
  value: null
})
a.test = {
  b: 'foo'
};
console.log(a.test.b);
```

(`writable` defaults to `false`, so you have to explicitly pass `writable: true` for the descriptor)

`configurable: false` means that the property descriptor can't be changed from a data descriptor to an accessor descriptor (or vice versa), nor can the property be removed from the object, but that doesn't prevent you from changing the actual value of the property, *if* the descriptor is writable.

Comment: and if ```writable:false```then what should i do about it?or I can do nothing?

Comment: That's right, if `writable` is false (or is missing, so that it defaults to false), there's nothing you can do about it, (un?)fortunately